# Recreating HTML/CSS Behavior with Styled-Components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a fairly annoying problem using Styled-Components in a React app. The class names of the HTML elements are very important, as is the dynamism of styled-components (via props passing). So it's important that both are used.

**tl;dr** I want to use a classname in CSS (and *not* HTML) without having to create an empty component or something.

I have a class with a dynamic classname, let's stay "style-123", where "123" is dynamically changed via state and is important for parity with the current setup. (IMO, the dynamic nature of the classname is preventing a solution.) The "style-123" classname is used in other HTML elements, *but* it is not a component itself so should not show up as an HTML element.

I have a component ("ComponentA") that has a classname of "component-a". This component's HTML should looking like the following:

```html
<div class="component-a">
   HELLO
</div>
```

and its Styles (in Dev Tools) should look like this:

```css
.style-123 .component-a {
    margin-left: -2%;
}
```

***where we now see the class ("style-123") added***. This should be the final result.

The general structure of the HTML is along the lines of:

```html
<div class="name-whatever style-123 another-classname">
   <div>
      <div class="component-a">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Problem**
I do not seem to be able to isolate "component-a" as an *HTML* classname for "ComponentA" while applying CSS as `.style-123 .component-a` via styled-components. In order for the HTML to have an isolated classname, the component (JSX) would need to be:

```js
<ComponentA className={'component-a'}/>
```

and the styled component:

```js
const ComponentA = styled.div`
   &.component-a {
      color: red;
   }
`
```

This is the only way I know how to link-up a component in JSX with its styled-component counterpart.

I cannot do:

```js
<ComponentA className={'component-a'}/>
```

and the styled component:

```js
const ComponentA = styled.div`
   &.style-123 .component-a {
      color: red;
   }
`
```

as this won't apply the styling since there's a classname-mismatch.

I've tried many combinations of SASS, all the ampersands and arrows and pluses and etc., over the last few hours. I hope this is feasible via styled-components as I need to declare classnames and have classnames dynamic as well as the CSS attributes and values, all passed via props. If there is another solution that doesn't use styled-components but maintains this dynamism, I am open to that.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: pretty sure https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#existing-css covers this topic?

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'm not sure that it does. It led me to declare `.style-213 .component-a` in a CSS stylesheet, while retaining `<ComponentA className={'component-a'}/>`. This has the desired result on the frontend (via Dev Tools). However, declaring the compound classes in a stylesheet makes those classes and styling static, whereas I need them to be dynamic, which is why I'm attempting this with styled-components.

Comment: Step back, and explain what you actually want to _achieve_ (not in code; what user-visible functionality are you trying to make happen here) because it sounds like you're trying to make what you think is a solution to your original problem work, rather than finding the right solution first.

Comment: Unfortunately, what I need to achieve for user-visible functionality _is_ what I've defined in the question: I need a single class on a component/HTML ("component-a") and two classes in the CSS (".style-123 .component-a"), wherein the first selector in the CSS declaration (".style-123") is dynamic and _not_ a component. I am attempting to achieve React parity with a vanilla HTML/JS/CSS structure.

Comment: No, that's the _code description of your solution_, not a description of what user functionality you're trying to achieve with your component(s). The user does not see "classes", it sees a UI, and it does something, and then that UI changes: what are you trying to make the user experience that makes you think you needed a component to dynamically toggled its own classes for that? (because maybe that's not the right solution and that's a far easier, better option that you didn't know about but folks looking at the tags you used do. We won't know until you explain that part of the problem).

Comment: Thanks. I understood your question. But I'm trying to emphasize that what I've explained is the end result of the user experience because the user is an engineer looking at this HTML element and right-clicking on it to open Dev Tools then inspecting the HTML and CSS, expecting there to be parity with the current vanilla HTML/CSS app that is in use. Hence, I am trying to figure out if it is feasible to recreate this vanilla HTML/CSS experience with React and styled-components. The code description of my solutions _is_ the UX description of my solution.

Comment: I totally agree with Mike here. What is the use case of the additional CSS classname? It sounds superfluous to any *actual* CSS styling, as in, you just simply want to dynamically add a class to the elements for some identification purpose. Maybe don't use `styled-components` for this? You can add a class to the `className` prop of any React component.

Comment: I would agree that it's superfluous to any actual CSS styling. Unfortunately, it's the parameters I'm stuck with since I need to recreate legacy code for the sake of parity with an old system. Thanks for the suggestions. I will continue to play with it and probably move away from styled-components.